# Ganeti 'template' based OS, possible?

Tags: xen, templates, ganeti

Just discovering ganeti and playing around; from what I saw it's only possible to create instances by 'de-bootstrapping' a flavour of OS.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have 'ready to go' templates like for example a 'LAMP' template or a 'DNS Server' template to choose from when creating the instance.

Haven't found much documentation on that; if anyone has an idea ..

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a different instance OS definition has is based on using disk images for deployment. It's called [ganeti-instance-image](http://code.osuosl.org/projects/ganeti-image) and should probably fit the role you need. The basic idea is manually creating the base image you want and then creating a filesystem dump or tarball that will be used by this OS definition. It works quite nicely!

Or, if you want to continue to use instance-debootstrap, you can create a variant that lists different `extra_pkgs=""` set to build out the LAMP template you want. Basically "templates" are like "variants" in Ganeti.

Comment: Excellent ! Right what I was looking for. Just a quick question, how do i './configure' when git-cloning ? Trying the 'autogen.sh' gives me a "autogen.sh: 13: aclocal: not found" (debian 6)

Comment: Stupid me; missing 'autotools' :)

Comment: Sorry again, but I dont understand 'how' your script actually integrates with ganeti's creation scripts; when doing gnt-os list it only shows me 'image+default'. Can you provide a quick howto to get started ?

Answer (score 2):

The howto you're looking for is in the manpage ganeti-os-interface, or online [here](http://docs.ganeti.org/ganeti/current/man/ganeti-os-interface.html). Please read it and if it's not explaining things correctly let us know at ganeti@googlegroups.com.

thanks,
iustin